# reference used firebase project in firebase function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have a firebase functions project, and I switch between projects (dev & prod) using the firebase cli command `firebase use [project]`

How can I figure out in my functions which project is used? I thougth it would be in `.firebaserc`, but that is not being updated by the cli command...

Thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the running function, you should be able to parse out project from the `FIREBASE_CONFIG` environment variable:

```
const {projectId} = JSON.parse(process.env.FIREBASE_CONFIG);
```

Comment: Addendum: `process.env.GCP_PROJECT` and `process.env.GCLOUD_PROJECT` (that you might have used in the past) are [no longer available](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/env-var#runtime_environment_variables_set_automatically), which is why [`process.env.FIREBASE_CONFIG`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env#automatically_populated_environment_variables) is used to get the current project ID.